# Using validation with ansible's expect variables

Tags: validation, ansible, expect

I'm using ansible to automate project deploy on machines. In one case I'm using ansible's `expect` option.

I have in my:

```
# initdb.yml

- hosts: all
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "username"
      prompt: "Username"
      private: no
    - name: "email"
      prompt: "Email"
      private: no
    - name: "password"
      prompt: "Password"
      private: yes
  roles:
    - initdb
```

and in:

```
# roles/.../main.yml

- expect:
    echo: yes
    command: 'env/bin/python manage.py createsuperuser'
    timeout: 5
    responses:
      'Username .*': '{{ username }}'
      'Email .*': '{{ email }}'
      'Password': '{{ password }}'
      'Password (again)': '{{ password }}'
  args:
    chdir: '{{ repo.path }}'
  tags:
    - superuser
```

It's for creating a superuser after applying django init migrations.

**Now let's go to the point**:

When I run this and somebody will type in for example too short password, whole process hangs up and I have to run it again using `tags` option.

**Question**:

Is there a way to attach validation to ansible's expect that it will just prompt in console that it's incorrect value and force user to type in correct value?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, `expect` module can't do validation for you.
You should avoid any interactivity in your playbooks.
If you need to validate parameters, do it manually at the very beginning of your playbook with `assert`:

```
- hosts: all
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "password"
      prompt: "Password"
      private: yes
  pre_tasks:
    - assert:
        that: password | length > 6
  roles:
    - initdb
```

Comment: ``You should avoid any interactivity in your playbooks.``. Could you give me example for expect usage then?

Comment: @turkus I mean to avoid user interaction (_force user to type in correct value_). Your `expect` example is OK, just validate your vars in the very beginning, so you can rerun playbook instantly.